# How do I use WaitHandler.WaitAll in MSTest without STA warnings?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, waithandle

Is there a way to unit test `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` when using Visual Studio's built-in unit testing solution.   When I try and run a test that uses this function within Visual Studio the test fails and when examining the test results the following error is displayed:

```
WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported
```

I'd like to be able to unit test the use of `WaitAll()` since an increasing amount of my API's code base is now moving to an `IAsyncResult` pattern as opposed to other means of doing multi-threaded operations.

**Edit**

Based on Anthony's suggestion here is a simple helper method that can be used to invoke such code in a unit test environment:

```
public static void TestInMTAThread(ThreadStart info)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(info);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

Comment: Which version of Visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 with option of moving to 2010 if necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have two problems. The first is the one you stated: You cannot wait on multiple Wait Handles [in an STA thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6(VS.80).aspx) (the MSTest thread apartment state). We can fix that with a manually created MTA thread.

```
public static void OnMtaThread(Action action)
{
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(action));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

The environment also has a [maximum wait handle limit](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-clr/1971/WaitHandles-must-be-less-than-or-equal-to-64-missing-documentation). In .NET 2.0, it appears to be hard coded to 64. Waiting on more than the limit will produce a `NotSupportedException`. You can use an [extension](http://gist.github.com/469917) method to wait on all wait handles in chunks.

```
public static void WaitAll<T>(this List<T> list, TimeSpan timeout)
    where T : WaitHandle
{
    var position = 0;
    while (position <= list.Count)
    {
        var chunk = list.Skip(position).Take(MaxWaitHandles);
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(chunk.ToArray(), timeout);
        position += MaxWaitHandles;
    }
}
```

And you'd rig them together like this in your test (in the Act or Assert part of the test)

```
OnMtaThread(() => handles.WaitAll(Timespan.FromSeconds(10)));
```

Comment: In this case, the `action` would be waiting on all handles. I'll update my answer to show an example unit test and how this all fits together.

Comment: So it requires changes in the productive code? It can't be fixed in the unit test only?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I think the premise is that you're rigging up wait handles _inside_ your test to test things like callbacks or threaded stuff.

Comment: Oh, I haven't had that problem yet... sounds like you need some kind of collaborator that checks the current thread state and executes the `OnMtaThread` action when necessary. Better yet, post a question with your context and errors!

Answer (score 2):

In [Visual Studio 2008 & 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404663%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) you can change your `.testsettings` file to run the tests under an MTA thread by adding `<ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />`.

```
<Execution>
     <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
</Execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Visual Studio 2010 only the following configuration made tests work.

```
<Execution>
     <ExecutionThread apartmentState="1" />
</Execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

For VS2008 the instructions are slightly different compared to VS2010. For VS2008, edit the testrunconfig file, and add the following to the TestRunConfiguration element:

```
<ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
```